# Create kmz file with jpegs that can be viewed in google earth

Tags: kml, geotagging

I need to add photos to a kmz file however my file which has the coordinates does not have a time/date field. So far everything i've found suggests georeferencing jpegs for kmz/kml needs to link on time via a gpx file.

I have a csv with the following fields: ID, X, Y, photo_id

I would think this would be more straight forward than relying on a time stamp however it's proving difficult.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a work around to create a kmz with photos:

Create a file (txt or csv) which contains an ID column, your x/y coordinates in two columns, and one column with the file path `<p><IMG SRC="IMAGE.jpg" width="400">`

Then run it through QGIS and export to KML.

Save the KML in a folder and add your photos inside another folder called "files" (so now you your KML file next to a folder called files inside a main folder). Zip the main folder and rename the file extension to kmz. The file will then open in Google Earth with your photos linked to each geographic point.